# Drop all data in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I would like to drop all data in a pandas dataframe, but am getting `TypeError: drop() takes at least 2 arguments (3 given)`. I essentially want a blank dataframe with just my columns headers.

```
import pandas as pd

web_stats = {'Day': [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 6],
             'Visitors': [43, 43, 34, 23, 43, 23],
             'Bounce_Rate': [3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(web_stats)

df.drop(axis=0, inplace=True)
print df
```

Comment: I do like @ayhan's solution, but I think `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)` would be faster and more efficient...

Comment: Agree with @MaxU -- it's actually about 100x faster (test dataframe with 1M rows and 10 cols)

Comment: `df.iloc[0:0]` is faster than the df construction actually. I guess you are comparing it to drop rather than iloc?

Comment: @ayhan, you are right, I was talking about `df.drop(...)`

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea to use `gc.collect()` afterwards?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You need to pass the labels to be dropped.

```
df.drop(df.index, inplace=True)
```

By default, it operates on `axis=0`.

You can achieve the same with

```
df.iloc[0:0]
```

which is much more efficient.

Comment: Should it not be df = df.iloc[0:0] ?

Answer (score 24):

My favorite:

```
df = df.iloc[0:0]
```

But be aware df.index.max() will be nan.
To add items I use:

```
df.loc[0 if math.isnan(df.index.max()) else df.index.max() + 1] = data
```

Answer (score 16):

My favorite way is:

```
df = df[0:0]
```

Comment: short and sweet, easy to remember!

Answer (score 11):

Overwrite the dataframe with something like that

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(None)
```

or if you want to keep columns in place

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to drop the dataframe, then you need to pass all columns. For me: the best way is to pass a list comprehension to the columns kwarg. This will then work regardless of the different columns in a df.

```
import pandas as pd

web_stats = {'Day': [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 6],
             'Visitors': [43, 43, 34, 23, 43, 23],
             'Bounce_Rate': [3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(web_stats)

df.drop(columns=[i for i in check_df.columns])
```

Answer (score -4):

This code make clean dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':[3,4]})
#clean
df = pd.DataFrame()
```

Comment: OP wrote: _I essentially want a blank dataframe with just my columns headers._