# Panda drop values in columns but keep columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Has the title say, I would like to find a way to drop the row (erase it) in a data frame from a column to the end of the data frame but I don't find any way to do so.

I would like to start with

```
A    B    C
-----------
1    1    1
1    1    1
1    1    1
```

and get

```
A    B    C
-----------
1        
1        
1
```

I was trying with

```
df.drop(df.loc[:, 'B':].columns, axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

But this delete the column itself too

```
A
-
1        
1        
1
```

am I missing something?

Comment: Check `df.loc[:, df.columns != 'A'] = ''`

Comment: There must be something in those cells, either a ```' '```, or ```np.nan```, or any kind of character.

Comment: I would like to make the drop but I only know the name of the last column I need to keep the row

Comment: I would like to keep the first row event if the column is empty

Comment: It is not very clear what you're trying to achieve..

Comment: Try this
`df.iloc[0:0]` Further examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173992/drop-all-data-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only know the column name that you want to keep:

```
import pandas as pd

new_df = pd.DataFrame(df["A"])
```

If you only know the column names that you want to drop:

```
new_df = df.drop(["B", "C"], axis=1)
```

For your case, to keep the columns, but remove the content, one possible way is:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df["A"], columns=df.columns)
```

Resulting df contains columns "A" and "B" but without values (NaN instead)

Comment: When I do that, as I said, I drop the first line ( B C ) to, but I want to keep it

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer. This is in fact very special use case.